# What happened to the bomb in Bender?

Tags: futurama, bender-rodriguez

On *Futurama* in the episode ["War is the H-Word"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Is_the_H-Word), Bender was fitted with a bomb that when Bender utters "Ass", would blow up an 'enemy' planet.

The bomb was modified to activate under a different word at the end of the episode.

Does that bomb ever get mentioned again? I remember something about the bomb being used again in another episode, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [suggestion in the closing dialogue](http://theinfosphere.org/Transcript%3aWar_Is_the_H-Word) is that Bender has guessed the new trigger word ("antiquing") and the bomb detonates, but he is still able to survive it:

> **Bender:** *(guessing the word)* "Compassion"? "Shrimptoast"? "Antiquing"? [There is an explosion.] I'm alright!

The apparent assumption is that the bomb was actually a dud, or just not enough to kill Bender. I've never heard another mention of this particular bomb in other episodes, but Bender has had *other* explosive devises in him before. For example, in the episode [*Rebirth*](http://theinfosphere.org/Rebirth), the Professor uses a doomsday device to replace Bender's failed power source. When the device eventually overloads and explodes, Bender survives, [exclaiming](http://theinfosphere.org/Transcript%3aRebirth):

> Geez, what's it take to kill me?

Yet again, an explosive device that falls short of destroying our precious bending unit.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the episode [When Aliens Attack](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/When_Aliens_Attack), Fry ironically notes how things seem to return to normal at in the end.

While it was ironic in that episode (because the world was on fire), with most others there's very little if any continuity in subsequent episodes, with a few exceptions (Leela's heritage, Nibbler's race, etc.)

So a bomb inside Bender will not remain in him in additional episodes.